# Shipping price not applied in configurable product in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

**Shipping price not applied in configurable product in magento 2.1**

I have used **Flat rate** shipping method for **shipping price** calculation in my project.

When I add **simple product** in shopping cart shipping price was applied successfully.

When I add **configurable product** in shopping cart shipping price was not applied.

In magento 1.9 its working perfectly.

```
Any new settings for configurable product?
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having this same behavior. Have you sorted it out ?

Comment: I received same error. Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience: shipping price/methods could be applied to products with assigned weight only (*Magento ver. 2.0.12*). That means problem is not connected to configurable products, just to those ones without weight.

**How to solve:**

Set 'Yes' in 'Weight: Does this have a weight?' section for each configurable product and its virtual copies.